# How to get a JS script console output in TWebbrowser?

Tags: delphi, mshtml, twebbrowser

I want to run a javascript code in TWebbrowser and get the console output of it. For instance, if i run this code in the console :

```
var a = 2; var b = 3; var c = a +b ; console.log('The result is '+ c);
```

I get this output on console :

```
The result is 5
```

The code i use to run a JS script with TWebbrowser is this :

```
twebbrowser1.navigate('javascript:var a = 2; var b = 3; var c = a +b ; console.log('The result is '+ c);');
```

It works, but i don't know how to get the console output. Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by " get the console output"?  Do you want the TWebBrowser to *display* the JS console or do you want to *capture* (in Delphi code) what output the console script produces?

Comment: In the latter case, you should not even be using a TWebBrowser to run the javascript at all.  Run the javascript directly, such as with [Windows Script Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t64z26x3.aspx) (the `IActiveScript` interface), `cscript.exe`, or other scripting engine.  It is wasteful to use a *visual* HTML component to perform *non-visual* script work by itself.

Comment: @MartynA It's like i said, i'd like to get the console output using my Delphi App.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need to run the script in a webpage, that's why i use TWebbrowser. The case in the question is just an example.

Comment: @delphirules your example is navigating the browser to a `javascript:` url that has an embedded script. You are not calling a script on a HTML page, so `TWebBrowser` is the wrong tool to use in your example. If you are doing something different in your real code, you should have shown that instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually i will manipulate the DOM in the page, via JS. I don't want to use MSHTML methods, i want to make a pure JS code because soon i will migrate from TWebbrowser to another embedded browser solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to MSDN, it looks like your (Delphi) app would need to implement the [`IDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj126732.aspx) interface.

Then you can connect an object instance of your `IDeveloperConsoleMessageReceiver` to the browser's current Document. Query the `TWebBrowser.Document` property for its [`IOleCommandTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683797.aspx) interface and then call its [`Exec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690300.aspx) method to issue a `IDM_ADDCONSOLEMESSAGERECEIVER` command.

Try that, and if you get stuck, try asking again.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy ! I lost the count about how many times you helped me not only here but in lot of other sources like the Embarcadero forums. Please take my warm THANK YOU VERY MUCH for such a great work you provide to the Delphi community. You rock !

Comment: Yes, I'm obliged to Remy, too, for editing my answer here (and for many other things,too!).

Comment: You can see the code here -- https://github.com/marcieldeg/consolemessagereceiver

Comment: I tried to compile the above code (from James) but got an error on line 152 on @CGID_MSHTML about difference between formal and actual parameters. Compiling with Delphi 10.3.3. Rio.